# C# Creating admin shortcut

Tags: c#, .net

I found this [article](http://vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp) but it does not contain support for run as admin..

Well i need to create a shortcut to notepad to edit a xml file, but i need notepad to run as administrator, how would i go about to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any good solution to this... so i created a simple .net app that required admin rights and used that one to start notepad..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the first result of Google search:

[Make shortcut always run as administrator](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/make-shortcut-always-run-as-administrator)
.